# jQuery demo code throwing error

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a dialog to my code. I was using the code referenced at https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default.

When I run this code exactly as it's shown in the source I get a console error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I'd expect the source example to work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this from an actual web server, or just opening the page in a web browser locally on a PC?

Comment: I'm running it locally.

Comment: Then you need to add a protocol to all your include files. For example `href="http://code.jquery.com` instead of `href="//code.jquery.com`. Otherwise the browser adds `file:` which won't work.

Comment: Cheers. I didn't know this was required for local. Of course it now makes perfect sense. Problem solved.